# How can I change the character limit of the search entry in the WhiskerMenu?

Tags: xfce, xfce-panel, whisker

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and like to put my searches directly into the Search entry in my Whisker Menu on Xfce4, but there's a limit of using only 14 characters in the search.

Is there a workaround or a configuration for this?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/948927/edit) and add the output of `lsb_release -d` in a code block (`{}` button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [a commit](https://github.com/gottcode/xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin/commit/dde745f5f26f85152b5b11e088c8d18c37205a2b) to the source code dating to 2015-12-27 whose description reads:

> Fix limited input length for search actions. (bug #12381)

I suppose the bug was solved by this commit, so you just need to **update to a newer version** to get rid of it, see [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin&searchon=names) for the versions provided by the different Ubuntu releases. You can try to install a newer version of `xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin` directly, however this may throw errors or don't work like expected – the best solution would be to just update your whole system to (at least) the current LTS 16.04.

#### Edit

It turns out Ubuntu 16.04 [has v1.5.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin) of `xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin`, but the bug [was fixed only in v1.5.2](https://github.com/gottcode/xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin/releases/tag/v1.5.2). I see two (practicable) alternatives for you:

1. Update your whole system to 16.10 and then 17.04
2. Try to update the package manually.

Even though I normally highly recommend staying with the package sources, in this particular case I advise you to update just the package to v1.5.2. You could also try the up-to-date version, but keeping the changes little makes it more likely to not throw errors.

**tl;dr**: [Download v1.5.2.tar.gz](https://github.com/gottcode/xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin/archive/v1.5.2.tar.gz) and install it following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1030/507051), but **do not** use `sudo make install`, but `sudo checkinstall` instead. You might have to install `checkinstall` first using `sudo apt install checkinstall`.

Comment: Strange i'm already using LTS 16.04 i don't know why this is not fixed in my installation, do you know if there's a way for me to update the entry myself in the source file, i can't file the `panel-plugin/query.h` file to make the changes.

Comment: That's not strange at all, see my edit above.

Comment: Sorry i was not updated when i typed the message, i gonna try your fix , at least now i know the cause,  thanks a lot.